# Why can I not get the android emulator to work on the sample .net Maui project?

Tags: .net, maui

I'm new to .net MAUI. I am going through the create your first .NET MAUI app on Microsoft's page and I am at the part it asks you to first create the android emulator and run it but it doesn't work. When it first starts it gives me a message "This machine does not have an Intel processor, which is required to accelerate the Android emulator". Do I really need an Intel processor? I am using an AMD build.

I have tried creating different types of emulators but I am just getting the same problem. When I ignore the message the emulator opens but the base maui program never starts and a message pops up on the emulator that says the UI doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I really need an Intel processor? I am using an AMD build.

AMD processor also support the `Hyper-V` Accelerate.

However, you need to check if your processor and system meet the following requirements by using this link to [Verify support for Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#verifying-support-for-hyper-v).

Then you need to [Enable Hyper-V acceleration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#enabling-hyper-v-acceleration), Enter windows features in the Windows search box and select Turn Windows features on or off in the search results. In the Windows Features dialog, enable both Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform.

Comment: Yep. This was the issue. My system did not meet the requirements. Time for an upgrade. Thank you.

Comment: Actually all I needed to do was to enable virtualization in my BIOS and now the emulator works.